# For every prime p , every commutative ring of characterstic p contains $F_{p}$ as a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This particular question was asked in Masters entrance for which I am preparing .

> Prove that :For every prime p , every  commutative ring of characterstic p contains $F_{p}$ as a subring .

If the ring contains unity and denote ring by R , then by taking the set S={ k.1| k belongs to R} and map $\phi$(k)=k.1 , we can easily see that S is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$/(p) .

> But there are two problems with this method :(i) The ring doesnot contains Unity .

(2) is this argument correct : the $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a field and as there only exists 1 field with p elements so it is isomporphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ .

Am i right ?

Comment: If the ring doesn't have a unit then how do you even define its characteristic?

Comment: Commutativity isn't needed. Probably the relevant convention is that a r**i**ng has a unit, _by definition_. Otherwise it would be merely a **rng**.

Comment: @mark A multiplicative identity doesn't seem important, although it simplifies the definition if you have it. If there is an $n\in\mathbb N^+$ such that $n\cdot x=0$ for all $x$ in the ring, you can pick the least such $n$. Otherwise say the characteristic is $0$. So one can say $R=(x)\subseteq F_2[x]$ has characteristic $2$ without having identity.  But this question obviously wants to assume the existence of an identity.

Comment: @Mark You are right, thanks!!